# Reseeding std::rand / c++11 <random>

Tags: c++, c, c++11, random

I am trying to implement a simple noise function that takes two integers and return a random float based on the seed combined with the two parameters.

using `std::mt19937` works great, but for some reason when I try to use `srand` with `rand()`, I get repeated numbers..

> **Note:** Using c++11 `seed` member function in a loop is really, really slow.

here are two terrains using both methods (with the same reseeding numbers):

c++11 random:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g{ rd() };
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> gen{ -1.0, 1.0 };

float getNoise(int x, int z) {
     g.seed(x * 523234 + z * 128354 + seed);
     return gen(g);
}
```

[image: c++11 random]

c random:

```
float getNoise(int x, int z) {
        std::srand(x * 523234 + z * 128354 + seed);
        return static_cast<float>(std::rand()) / RAND_MAX * 2.0f - 1.0f;
}
```

[image]

## To the questions:

1. Is there a faster way to reseed the c++11 pseudo-random number ?
2. Why doesn't the `srand` work as expected?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Ok sorry for not being clear, and, I know maybe I am wrong but let me try to explain again, I use reseeding because I use the same x and z coordinate's when iterating (not the same iteration).

If I remove the reseeding I will get this result:
[image]

Comment: I'm not going to tell you not to reseed, because that part makes sense. What doesn't make sense is why you are reseeding *in a loop*. You only need to seed the RNG at the beginning, before you start using it. You don't need to reseed it each time through the loop...

Comment: Isn't seeding a PRNG with its own output highly likely to make it approach deterministic? Why did you feel the need to reseed every iteration? i.e. what happened/happens when you reseed only once as recommended everywhere else; how do both versions look in that case

Comment: I needed to reseed it because I didn't want to get a completely random number's and I used the same x and z coordinate's several times (not in the same iteration), that is why I needed to reseed, you have any other suggestion?

Comment: You're reseeding based on `x`, `z`, and `seed`... if those values are are the same, your seed will be too... so you'll get the same numbers from `rand()`.

Comment: @Dmitri why doesn't it happen in the c++11 random version ?

Comment: "I get repeated numbers.. [implying those are unwanted]" vs "I didn't want to get a completely random number's" => Pick one. You realise these are mutually exclusive, right? If you want something semi-random, then define an appropriate distribution. Don't just try to bend an RNG to be 'not quite so random' with the first hack you think of.

Comment: Perhaps if you don't want a completely random distribution, you should set the limitiation and apply random numbers to get a variation.

Comment: So which of the three (edit) images do you want? If none of them, what **do** you want?

Comment: @WeatherVane I want The first one, but because I am reseeding it with the c++11 random library it is really slow (I know I am not suppose to reseed it that way, but how could I reseed it better? Or there is a way around reseeding it without causing the terrain to look like image #3)

Comment: I could be mistaken but it looks to me like you found a pot-luck way to reduce the "randomness" of one generator and you are wondering why your pot-luck approach is not working so well for a different generator. I think you are going to have to rework your algorithm to rely on actual randomness rather than by trying to impose just the right amount of order onto chaos.

Comment: @Galik Thanks, I will try to find a different solution

Comment: @NaorHadar Yes, you need to use a distribution and subsequent processing that matches the sort of result you want to see, while still providing enough randomness to be interesting. Hacking around be reseeding, etc is not likely to be reliable between different stdlibs/runtimes and whatnot, so you need to figure out a method that is. The plus side is that you'll have immeasurably more control over the sort of output you'll get in return.

Comment: @underscore_d Thanks, I actually used an article pseudo code so I didn't really thought that through. I am now working on finding a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am trying to implement a simple noise function that takes two integers and return a random float based on the seed combined with the two parameters.
>
> Please don't say I shouldn't reseeding, I want to reseed on purpose.

You are purposely breaking it and asking us why it is broken, with the caveat that we aren't allowed to mention the gorilla in the room.

Don't reseed.

[edit]
**Alright, as per comment request, *here's an answer:***

1) No, there is no faster way to reseed a PRNG, which you shouldn't be doing anyway. Properly, you should be seeding and then “warming up” the PRNG by discarding a few thousand values.

2) The reason `rand()` (and, even though you don't believe it, any other PRNG you use) doesn't work is because your `getNoise()` function is incorrect.

Your third image is correct. It is the result you *should* expect from simply returning a clamped random value.

You have attempted to modulate it by messing with the seed and, because of an apparent visual goodness in your first attempt, concluded that it is the correct method. However, what is really happening is you are simply crippling the PRNG and seeing the result of that. (It is more clear in the `rand()` attempt because its seed more crudely defines the resulting sequence, which itself has a smaller period than the Mersenne Twister.)

(Attempting to modify it by skewing the (x,z) coordinate is also a red herring. It doesn't affect the actual randomness of the output.)

**TL;DR**
*You're doing it wrong.*

If you want to generate terrain maps, you should google around fractal terrain generation. In fact, here's a decent link for you: http://www.gameprogrammer.com/fractal.html

You will find that it takes a little more work to do it, but that the methods are very pleasingly simple and that you can very easily tweak them to modify your results.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really interesting article on terrain. And heh, I had no idea 'warming up' was a thing. This document elaborates: http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/d.jones/GoodPracticeRNG.pdf +1 for the edit!

Comment: That's a pretty decent article. The only nit I would pick on first pass is the (bad) advice to use a hash on your seeds. Hashes don't belong anywhere near the seeding or production of random numbers... If it matters, use a CSPRNG to seed your PRNGs -- every system has something that will do.

Answer (score 3):

The random number generator generates a *sequence* of random values from an initial seed, and is not meant to be used to generate single random values in function of a seed. So it should be initialized with `g.seed(seed)`, and then be called in a fixed order for all (x, y) values, without reseeding each time. This will give random values efficiently, with the expected distribution.

For example:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 g{ rd() };
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> gen{ -1.0, 1.0 };

constexpr std::size_t nx = 100;
constexpr std::size_t nz = 100;
float noise[nx][nz];

void generateNoise() {
     g.seed(seed);
     for(int x = 0; x < nx; ++x) for(int x = 0; x < nx; ++x)
          noise[x][z] = gen(g);
     return gen(g);
}
```

Comment: I am not able to run your snippet. Would you suggest value for the "seed" variable and method to use the "gen" function? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you'd want to continuously re-seed - that seems pointless and slow. But that's not what you are asking, so...

1. `rand` produces very poor quality random numbers. Very low period and usually based on a linear congruential generator (not good). Also, the seed size is very small. Don't use it - `<random>` exists for a reason.
2. The way you seed using `srand` seems to depend very much on the `x` and `z` values you pass in and that you then multiply by large numbers which likely leeds to overflows and truncation when passing to `srand`, meaning that (due to the limited number of possible seed values) you'll be reusing the same seed(s) often.

Some relevant links you may want to visit:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful